# Odd Kerberos Hosts After HD Wipe, and fresh OS re-install

Tags: malware, intrusion

After reformatting my hard disk and rebuilding/re-installing the latest macOS operating system, I found the following IP addresses after running Kerberos.internal.com:

kerberos.internal.com has address 96.126.123.244

kerberos.internal.com has address 45.33.2.79

kerberos.internal.com has address 45.79.19.196

kerberos.internal.com has address 45.56.79.23

kerberos.internal.com has address 45.33.23.183

kerberos.internal.com has address 198.58.118.167

[image: command output]

These IPs belong to a web hosting company called Linode LLC out of New Jersey.  These IP addresses are also listed in the Abuse IDB website with reports of XSS attacks and more.  I just want a sanity check - after wiping my hard disk and re-installing my OS and immediately running this command that this is highly indicative of the presence of sophisticated malware right?

I want to add that this is a personal machine, not used for work, or associated with any dc.

Comment: You ran `host kerebos.internal.com` which does a lookup of the IPs for that domain name. Anyone who runs that command will get the exact same output. See `man host`.

Answer (score 2):

`internal.com` is a domain name registered on the public Internet (to whom, we don't know, because the WHOIS is private).  It is not, as you might have suspected, internal to your network or company, unless your company just so happens to have registered that domain name.  It may be that your organization is using its own DNS server to serve internal domains as `internal.com`, but that's not a good idea and they should stop using other people's domains for that purpose.

It appears that the owners of this domain have specified a wildcard record in their DNS, so all hostnames under `internal.com` resolve to the same IP addresses, whether that's `www.internal.com`, `kerberos.internal.com`, or `unprintable.internal.com`.

As a result, this is not the Kerberos server you were intending to use; it's just some unrelated domain, and its configuration is not indicative of anything nefarious.  I haven't tested, but I suspect it won't even respond to Kerberos packets at all.

Comment: This is a personal machine, with no Kerberos authentication being used.  To reiterate, these IPs are present after a hard drive wipe and a new OS install from apple servers.  I literally finished the install, created a user account, and ran a few artifact scans that produced the output above.  I didn’t even get a chance to log into WiFi.  The Linode hosted IPs are also flagged on abuse dbs.  I respectfully disagree - this is evidence of a firmware, or kernel level exploit.  Especially when considered in conjunction with other suspect artifacts that piqued my interest to begin with.

Comment: This hostname is being served using DNS to the public internet.  Anyone can query them; I did, and so can you.  The fact that you can query DNS like everybody else is not an indication that your system is compromised; in fact, it's an indication that you have normal network functionality.  Unless you can provide some evidence that these IP addresses are somehow attacking or connecting to your machine, there's no evidence here of compromise.